# Wrong number of parameters (parametrized query)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, informix, parameterized-query

Q:

When i try to execute the following parametrized query:

```
INSERT INTO days (day,short,name,depcode,studycode,batchnum) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

through `command.ExecuteScalar();`

throws the following exception:

> ERROR [07001] [Informix .NET provider]Wrong number of parameters.

Where is the problem?

**EDIT:**

```
 public static int InsertDays(List<Day> days)
        {

            int affectedRow = -1;
            Dictionary<string, string> daysParameter = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                foreach (Day a in days)
                {
                    daysParameter.Add("day", a.DayId.ToString());
                    daysParameter.Add("short", a.ShortName);
                    daysParameter.Add("name", a.Name);
                    daysParameter.Add("depcode", a.DepCode.ToString());
                    daysParameter.Add("studycode", a.StudyCode.ToString());
                    daysParameter.Add("batchnum", a.BatchNum.ToString());

                    affectedRow = DBUtilities.InsertEntity_Return_ID("days", daysParameter);
                    daysParameter.Clear();
                    if (affectedRow < 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
            }

            return affectedRow;

        }
```

---

```
public static int InsertEntity_Return_ID(string tblName, Dictionary<string, string> dtParams)
        {
            int Result = -1;
            DBConnectionForInformix DAL_Helper = new DBConnectionForInformix("");
            string[] field_names = new string[dtParams.Count];
            dtParams.Keys.CopyTo(field_names, 0);
            string[] field_values = new string[dtParams.Count];
            string[] field_valuesParam = new string[dtParams.Count];
            dtParams.Values.CopyTo(field_values, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < field_names.Length; i++)
            {
                field_valuesParam[i] = "?";
            }
            string insertCmd = @"INSERT INTO " + tblName + " (" + string.Join(",", field_names) + ") values (" + string.Join(",", field_valuesParam) + ");SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

        Result = int.Parse(DAL_Helper.Return_Scalar(insertCmd));
        return Result;
        }
```

---

Comment: should that not be `command.ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: @Eben: I suspect that it's ExecuteScalar due to the "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY" part.

Comment: and where have you added parameter values? You should have a number of lines adding to `command.Parameters`...

Comment: @Eben: No, he's selecting `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, so he expects the value returned from that (you need to scroll to the right).

Comment: Ah! Missed the `select`.  My bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown where you're actually populating the parameter *values*. Given that you've got the right number of question marks, I suspect that's where the problem lies.

EDIT: Okay, now you've posted more code, it's obvious what's going wrong: your `Return_Scalar` method isn't accepting any actual values! You're not *using* `field_values` anywhere after populating it. You need to set the parameters in the command.

(You should also look at [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx), by the way...)

Comment: @just_name: I've edited my answer. You're not actually telling the database what values to use.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that where you are providing the parameters that one of the values is not null.  That may cause the provider to ignore the parameter.  If this is your issue pass `DBNull`.

**EDIT**

As Jon stated you need to use `command.Parameters` to give the command the parameters to use in the query.